# How to get the label of a column which has the max value from the list if columns in SPSS?

Tags: statistics, spss

Let's say I have a table which has the below structure.

```
Column1(integer), Column2(integer), Column3(integer)
```

I would like to do a max operation among Column1, Column2, and Column3 and assign the label of the column which has the maximum value to a new column.

```
Column1(integer), Column2(integer), Column3(integer), Max_among_columns
```

E.G.

```
Column1, Column 2, Column3, Max_among_columns
   2         3        5        Column3
```

Does anyone know how can I do that?

Comment: what column should be selected if two columns contain the maximum value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
string Max_among_columns (a10).
compute #maxnum=-1000. /* please select some number that's certain to be smaller than the minimum.
do repeat clmn = column1 column2 column3 / clmnName = "column1" "column2" "column3".
    do if clmn > #maxnum.
        compute #maxnum = clmn.
        compute Max_among_columns = clmnName.
    end if.
end repeat.
exe.
```

If more than one columns contain the max value, the first of them will be selected.
If you prefer the last of them to be selected, replace this:

```
do if clmn > maxnum.
```

with this:

```
do if clmn >= maxnum.
```